# How to dockerize a Visual Studio SQL Database Project?

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core

I have a solution consisting of different small web-services, which right now I can simply build and run each in their own container via docker-compose.

Now, another service will be added, which will need some data access. Since running a mssql server on in a docker container is rather easy and basically consists of one entry in the docker compose, I would like to do the following:

- Create a SQL Database project and add it to my solution
- Configure the database project, so that it fits the need of the web service
- build a containerized SQL-Sever and automatically publish the database schema from my database project
- build the web service and connect it up with the containerized SQL server

The goal is, that after running docker-compose, everything should be up and running.

Is this possible as described?

One additional note: The whole thing is just a hobby project, I want to get familiar with docker, APIs and access to databases.

Comment: You "dockerize" applications like SQL Server itself, not projects. A database project is a description of the database, not the database itself. You can download and run a SQL Server container (check [Quickstart: Run SQL Server container images with Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash)) and deploy the database project to it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that is exactly what I was asking (maybe not formulated in the clearest way): Can running a SQL Server container and then deploying the database project to it be automated via docker-compose?

Comment: A database project produces a `dacpac` file that can be used to publish databases. You can include that file in your image and deploy it using `sqlpackage`. [This blog post](https://jonboulineau.me/blog/sql-server/sql-server-database-in-docker) shows how to automate the entire process - create a container using a SQL Server image as the base, install SqlPackage with RUN in the dockerfile itself and finally publish the database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Perfect, I'll have a read! Thanks a lot!